# Breezejs, on save changes primary key value set null on some transactions

Tags: angularjs, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api2, breeze

Let me provide the detail description of application structure first,

1. We have web api in the application server: Web api has breeze controller on top of the web api application and we are using Entity Framework for the ORM
2. Web Application: MVC web application, where we are using Angularjs - breezejs for the EF handling

We have widget kind of forms which represents one single entity called profile and the following 7 forms which are one to one relation with the profile entity

While start entering the details, we have created a formatted Primary key for profileID and we are using the same If as primary key for other tables as well. Along with this we are having profileId as foreign key.

When we are saving the forms, it works most of the situation but some times the primary keys for sub entities (i.e. other than profile entity profileId) will be set null and it through the exception as primary key should not be null value.

unusual situation here would be, we are using profileId as primary key for all the one to one related table.

This issue killing our process, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you narrow down the situations in which it doesn't work?  If you don't use Breeze, but create all the entities on the server side using pure EF, do you get the same problem?

Comment: Thanks Steve, I have found the problem now but not able to find out the root cause of it. we are creating one Primary key and using it in a table A, If table B Refer table A as foreign key, we are using the same foreign key as Primary key in table B. what ever the reason it gets cleared some time. now I have created new primary key for table B instead of using reference key as primary key